# CSS and JS are not loading when i deploy the site on github, netlify

Tags: javascript, html, css, github-pages, netlify

https://github.com/MadhavaY/RandomQuotesGenerator  here is the link to the repository. HTML is loading but css and js are not. Link to the website https://madhavay.github.io/RandomQuotesGenerator/. I saw other answers too but i could not get where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello madhava I reviewed your project and found out that you are still using your local paths to link your css and javascript

```html
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='css' media='screen' href='/All Projects/randomqotesproject/randomquotes.css'>
```

just change `/All Projects/randomqotesproject/randomquotes.css` to
`./randomquotes.css`

Comment: hey thanks for replying. It still does not work. I opened it on firefox, it shows no css is attached.

Comment: check [this](https://github.community/t/css-not-being-applied-in-pages/10466) post out

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the path of both files.
As is:

```
<script src="/All Projects/randomqotesproject/randomquotes.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' type='css' media='screen' href='/All Projects/randomqotesproject/randomquotes.css'>
```

If you remove the path, e.g:

```
/All Projects/randomqotesproject/
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried to edit the path, i think i have to check in my folders

Answer (score 0):

If changing the path doesn't work for you, you can easily add a URL to the CSS and JS instead.
EX: https://madhavay.github.io/RandomQuotesGenerator/randomquotes.css